# Checkable not toggled when using handler that touches the UI

Tags: java, android, scala

I have a custom CursorAdapter which sets a handler for OnCheckedChangeListener inside bindView (the layout in newView implements the Checkable interface). '=>' is the anonymous function syntax in scala:

```
def setTaskCheckboxToggleListener() = {
  val v = view.findViewById(R.id.taskCheckbox).asInstanceOf[CheckBox]
  v.setOnCheckedChangeListener(
    (buttonView: CompoundButton, isChecked: Boolean) => {
      handler(buttonView, isChecked)
    }
  )
}
```

The adapter is used with a listView. Now the handler is set once in the activity containing the listView using:

```
listView.setAdapter(Tasks.adapter(context))
listView.setChoiceMode(AbsListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
listView.getAdapter().registerCheckBoxStateChangeHandler((buttonView: CompoundButton, _) => {
  findViewById(R.id.commandButton).astInstanceOf[Button].setText("✓")
}
```

This handler for some reason prevents the checkbox from being toggled. In comparison, the checkbox just works with an empty handler or a handler that doesn't call .setText on the UI element. What could be the problem here?

Checkable layout used in the Adapter, the xml file in res/ has a CheckBox element:

```
import android.content.Context
import android.util.AttributeSet
import android.view.View
import android.widget.{CheckBox, Checkable, CheckedTextView, RelativeLayout}

class TaskLayout(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet)
  extends RelativeLayout(context, attrs) with Checkable {
  private var checkbox: CheckBox = _

    override def onFinishInflate(): Unit = {
      super.onFinishInflate();

      for (i <- 0 to getChildCount()) {
        val v = getChildAt(i)
        if (v.isInstanceOf[CheckBox])
          checkbox = v.asInstanceOf[CheckBox];
      }
    }

    override def isChecked(): Boolean = {
      if (checkbox != null)
        checkbox.isChecked()
      else
        false
    }

    override def setChecked(checked: Boolean) =
      if (checkbox != null) checkbox.setChecked(checked)

    override def toggle() =
      if (checkbox != null) checkbox.toggle();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Commenting out listView.setChoiceMode(AbsListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE) solved the problem.